# Pdf file and Png file colors printed differently from the same printer

Tags: color, print-design, pdf, png, digital-printing

I have a design in png and pdf formats. The png file was printed fine from Microsoft Photos and the colors were accurate. The colors of the same design however became brighter and lighter when I printed it as a Pdf file. I am new to design, does anyone know why is this happening, since the printer was able to print the correct colors from the png file?

Thank you so much!!

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Have you tried using Adobe Reader to print the PDF?

Comment: Hi! Yes, I used Adobe Reader to print the pdf

Comment: This is probably color profile related. Could be many things. Where and how did you make the PDF? Did you perhaps convert to some CMYK profile when creating the PDF? Your printer might misinterpret CMYK files. Are you aware of which *Color Management* settings you use under *Advanced Print Setup* when printing from Acrobat? Which color profile does the PNG have? Does MS Photos honor that profile or does it perhaps assign sRGB?

Comment: Are these related Q&As: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/131289/126327 and https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/37138/126327 ?